# how to count different rows from the same field in one sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

hi I have one table which I am trying to get the count of different rows on the same row field for example I a have this rows

```
Function field1 field2 field3
'dog'    1      1      5
'dog'    1      1      5
'cat'    1      1      5
'dog'    1      2      6
```

The output for this table should be:

```
Function count
'dog'    2
'cat'    1
```

because there are two different rows for 'dog' (some of the field are different) and one row for 'cat'

thank you so much

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to count rows identical based on a given subset of fields, this would be:

```
 SELECT func, COUNT(*) FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT func, field1, field2 FROM yourtable
 ) AS tmp GROUP BY func;
```

This first distincts all the rows, so you get

```
'dog'    1      1      5
'cat'    1      1      5
'dog'    1      2      6
```

and then counts the first field, thus giving 2 and 1.

You can even do something like

```
 SELECT func, COUNT(*) AS different, SUM(total) AS total FROM (
     SELECT   func, field1, field2, field3, COUNT(*) AS total 
            FROM yourtable
     GROUP BY func, field1, field2, field3
 ) AS tmp GROUP BY func;
```

which will give:

```
 func   different   total
 dog    2           3
 cat    1           1
```

Comment: You missed the `group by`

Comment: Thanks, @JorgeCampos . I guess I sort of fired from the hip :-(

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the results you are looking for:

```
Select  Function, Count(*) As Count
From
(
    Select  Distinct
            Function,
            Field1,
            Field2,
            Field3
    From    YourTable
) As A
Group By Function
```